# Sharing objects between threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I ran into some issues when using threads in Python.

What I need is:

Thread 1

- Start thread 2, give it 'data' object as parameter
- Do some work
- Stop thread 2
- Check results

Thread 2

- Read data for thread 1 in loop

That I implemented roughly as

```
class ReaderThread(threading.Thread)
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit:
            somehow modify self.data

    def stop(self):
        self.exit = True
        self.join()
```

The main thread creates an instance of ReaderThread and calls start() then some seconds later it calls stop().

```
class MainThread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = set()
        self.thread = ReaderThread(self.data)

    def function(self):
        self.thread.start()
        whoptydoo
        self.thread.stop()
```

Problem is, thread1 doesn't really modify the 'exit' variable for thread2 and thread2 (the ReaderThread) doesn't modify 'data' for thread1. So there is obviously some memory sharing issue here.

My idea was "it's proly all pointers", which doesn't seem to be correct.
What is the correct way to do this please?

Comment: I suppose you create two instances of `ReaderThread` and then run them. Well, `self` refers to instance and each instance has its own state. So, obviously, thread1 and thread2 will have their own values of `exit`, not share the same one.

Comment: @go2nirvana There is just one ReaderThread, I added some code

Comment: then what is second thread you are talking about in the question?

Comment: Thread1 = main thread, Thread2 = ReaderThread

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66489894/6367213) seems to resolve your issue. Either accept it, or close this question, since your error seems to have been caused by a typo.

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366137/6367213).

Comment: Erm.. what was my typo again?

Comment: @Pyjong except  the missing `:` there is nothing in your question that seems to prevent your code from working. If you want us to solve your problem, show us your problem.

Comment: I don't really know what the problem is. Ok, just give me a few hours and if there's no progress I'll close and delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RenderThread` class does not seem to be complete (missing `:`, and `Thread` initialisation).
Once completed, your example seems to work as expected.

**EDIT** after the example in the question was changed, it still works...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import threading

class ReaderThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = data
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        t0=time.time()
        while not self.exit:
            # somehow modify self.data
            time.sleep(0.25)
            self.data.add(int(100.0*(time.time()-t0)))

    def stop(self):
        self.exit = True
        self.join()

class MainThread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = set()
        self.thread = ReaderThread(self.data)

    def function(self):
        self.thread.start()
        time.sleep(2) # whoptydoo
        self.thread.stop()

mt=MainThread()
mt.function()
print(mt.data) # {225, 100, 200, 75, 175, 50, 150, 25, 125}
```

Comment: Ah.. sorry, I am actually calling super().__init__() in my code I just forgot to type it out here. Do the parameters to super() matter? (ReaderThread does not directly inherit anything else)

Comment: @Pyjong For your use case, the default [`Thread` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the deal: You have `data` field at `ReaderThread` and `data` field at `MainThread`. When you execute this `self.data = smth` in `ReaderThread` you set this value for `ReaderThread` field, but you never access any attributes of `MainThread`. Both instances have similarly-named fields, but they are not the same.

To achieve what you want you should either return a value from `ReaderThread.run` or pass `MainThread` instance to `ReaderThread` to be able to modify it. Looks like option 2 will suit you better.

```
class ReaderThread(threading.Thread)
    def __init__(self, main_instance):
        self.main = main_instance
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit:
            self.main.data = whatever

    def stop(self):
        self.exit = True
        self.join()

class MainThread():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = set()
        self.thread = ReaderThread(self)

    def function(self):
        self.thread.start()
        whoptydoo
        self.thread.stop()
```

P.S. After taking a closer look, i've got another idea of what you did wrong. As `MainThread.data` is a `set()` and thus mutable - your code would work as is, but only if you exactly **modify** `data`, but not reassign it (which, i suspect, you could have done).

Comment: I only use with data.add()/data.remove(). I'm gonna try passing the instance of MainThread then.

Comment: Humm.. no, doesn't seem to help :( But let's put self.data aside for a bit. I think calling the stop function also doesn't change the self.exit for the reader thread and there I was already using the instance of the whole thread. The call to self.join() just hangs.. understandably..

Comment: @Pyjong What version of Python do you use? CPython? Jython? on which platform?

Comment: 3.9. on Windows